# how to signal EOF to psycopg2.copy_from()?

Tags: psycopg2

I'm trying to read from one (non-postgres) cursor and use the results to feed psycopg2.copy_from().  I seem to have everything working fine, EXCEPT the EOF condition.  I have a wrapper for my cursor that turns it into a file-like object, and in that read() method I have:

```
row = self.readline()
if not row:
    return ""
```

But this causes the copy_from(cursor_as_file, 'cm_outgoing') to choke with

```
ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: ""
CONTEXT:  COPY cm_outgoing, line 533, column id: ""
```

This kinda makes sense, as the first field in cm_outgoing is an integer, and passing a zero-length string.  Should I be signaling EOF differently?  Or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 1):

The error was in a different place.  At another point, I had a double-newline in the file.  I'm not sure why copy_from() didn't complain there, but fixing the double-newline seems to have taken care of this problem.